# why don't you see the "keys" in the json?

Tags: java, spring-boot, stored-procedures, spring-data-jpa

when I enter postman, I get the json, but without his "keys" why? Maybe I'm making a mistake and I haven't noticed. Some help please.

I am using a stored procedure to be able to do a crud.

this is the json that shows me postman. Shows me without his "key"

```
{
    "data": [
        [
            1,
            "aaa",
            "aaa@gmail.com"
        ],
        [
            2,
            "bbb",
            "bbb@gmail.com"
        ],
        [
            3,
            "ccc",
            "ccc@gmail.com"
        ]
    ]
}
```

I would like to get something like this.

```
{
    "data": [
        {
          userCod: 1,
          userName: "aaa",
          userEmail: "aaa@gmail.com"
        },
        {
          userCod: 2,
          userName: "bbb",
          userEmail: "bbb@gmail.com"
        },
        {
          userCod: 3,
          userName: "ccc",
          userEmail: "ccc@gmail.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

I leave the code

```
public class ApiResponse {
    private List<UserTest> data;

    public List<UserTest> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<UserTest> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbUsers")
public class UserTest implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "userCod")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "userName")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "userEmail")
    private String email;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

```
@Repository
public class ClienteDaoImpl implements IClienteDao{

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager em;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public ApiResponse mntUsers(int op) {
        ApiResponse api = new ApiResponse();
        Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
        ProcedureCall call = session.createStoredProcedureCall("sp_MntUser");
        call.registerParameter(1, Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        call.setParameter(1, op);
        call.execute();
        api.setData(call.getResultList());
        return api;
    }

}
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/mntUsers")
public class ClienteController {

    @Autowired
    private ClienteServiceImpl serviceImpl;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> CrudUsers(@RequestParam(value = "option", required = true) Integer op) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(serviceImpl.mntUsers(op),HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

Comment: The `call.getResultList()` return `a array of objects` then you will always get your first response, if you want to convert then you should convert each objects array to `UserTest`

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: Can you try using the @JSONProperty annotation for JSON serialisation?

Comment: I tried, but the @JsonProperty does not work.

Comment: @makoto I wrote an answer, check it !

Answer (score 0):

Create a method called `getCollectionType`

```
public static <T, C extends Collection<T>> C getCollectionType(Iterable<?> from, C to, Class<T> listClass) {
    for (Object item: from) {
        to.add(listClass.cast(item));
    }
    return to;
}
```

Then use it on the following line:

```
api.setData(getCollectionType(call.getResultList(), 
                              new ArrayList<UserTest>(), 
                              UserTest.class));
```

Comment: it does not work. I get this error : "Cannot cast [Ljava.lang.Object; to com.proyecto.app.entity.UserTest"

Comment: Do I need to have a "User" entity? as you can see, I have created an entity "ApiResponse", to store all the results generated by my stored procedure in my attribute "data"

Comment: Yeah, I think so because when retrieving from stored procedure then you get the error you mentioned...

Comment: Is it so difficult to get a json result? or my code is very bad? A help please.
It's much easier with c # and why is java so complicated?